# Lista de asistencia según día de la semanas en SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

¿Cómo puedo hacer para obtener los días se asistencia según los días de semana y la cantidad de días?

- Hago mi matrícula (solo lunes, miércoles y viernes).
- Luego la cantidad es de `N` días.
- Entonces tendría de resultado que puedo asistir los dias

Lunes 15 de mayo  (día 1)
Miércoles  17 de mayo (día 2)
Viernes 19 de mayo (día 3)
.... así sucesivamente hasta completar `N` días.

También dependo de una fecha de inicio la cual en este caso es 15/05/2017.

Comment: las preguntas sobre base de datos deben incluir el esquema para que podamos construir un sql.. ademas de los SQL que ya intentaste.. y ademas, tu problema es en SQL o C#.. y que tiene que ver ASP.net en esto? por favor corrige la pregunta para poder ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes identificar los días ya mencionados (L-M-V), lo logras usando la función [DATEPART](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql).

Esta función te devolverá el número del día en la semana, que va desde el 1 al 7 (lunes a domingo, respectivamente) e irá repitiendo durante el resto de las semanas. De este modo ya puedes filtrar los días que necesites.

Por último solo faltaría los días de asistencia, el cuál obtienes con [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms186734.aspx).

Aquí el código:

```
DECLARE @TABLA TABLE (Fecha DATE)
DECLARE @Fecha DATE = '20160515'
DECLARE @n TINYINT = 1

WHILE @n < 10
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @TABLA (Fecha) VALUES (@Fecha);
   SET @Fecha = DATEADD(DD, 1, @Fecha)
   SET @n = @n + 1
END

SELECT
   TABLA.Fecha
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TABLA.Fecha) NroClase
   , TABLA.NroSemana
FROM
   (SELECT  Fecha, DATEPART(DW, Fecha) DiaSemana, DATEPART(WK, Fecha) NroSemana FROM @TABLA) AS TABLA --días semana, número semana
WHERE
   DiaSemana IN (1, 3 ,5)
```

Espero haya podido ser de ayuda.

PD. Usé una tabla y un while solo para obtener las fechas para el ejemplo.

Comment: Gracias amigo ahora lo pruebo

Comment: De nada, saludos.